# Angular 5 : Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, rxjs

I have tried many days on fixing this error over stackoverflow , Since i'm new to angular now I just need to ask from the community.I've been working on the JWT authentication

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
>       at RawMaterialComponent.loadRawMaterialsByCompany (raw-material.component.ts:774)

I have a service call as below in a component

```js
    private loadRawMaterialsByCompany(callback: any) {
    let serviceSubscriptions =this.rawMaterialService.getRawMaterialsByCompany().subscribe(data => {
      this.rawMaterials = data;
      this.rawMaterialLoading = false;
    }, 
     error => this.handleError(error));
    }
```

and the service is as below

```js
     getRawMaterialsByCompany() {
        const url = this.raw_material_api_endpoint + 'Company/' + this.company_id;
        return this.get(url);
      }
```

above service calls redirected to base service and it implements all http requests ie: get ,  post

What i want to do here is if the access token is expired i want to refresh the token. using a post request

```js
     protected get(url: string) {
        if (this.isTokenExpired(localStorage.getItem('userToken'))) {

            this.getOriginalDataset(url).then((val)=>{

            this.getTokenfromService()
            return(val)
          });
        } else {
          return this.http.get(url)
            .map(this.extractRequests)
            .catch(this.handleError);
        }


    protected post(url: string, body: any) {
        if (url.includes("RefreshToken") || url.includes("Login") || url.includes("Logout")) {
          return this.http.post(url, body, { headers: this.getHeaders() })
            .map(this.extractRequests)
            .catch(this.handleError);
        }
        else {
            return this.http.post(url, body, { headers: this.getHeaders() })
              .map(this.extractRequests)
              .catch(this.handleError);

        }

      }
```

**per now i'm not going to refresh token for post requests

getOriginalDataset() method brings the requested data for the raw material component

getTokenfromService() method get the new access token and refresh token to store in local storage

```js
    sendoriginalDataset(originalUrl):Promise<any>{
        return new Promise(resolve => {
        const dataSet= this.http.get(originalUrl, { headers: this.getHeaders() })
        .map(this.extractRequests)
        .catch(this.handleError);
        resolve(dataSet)
        });
      }

    async getTokenfromService() {

        const base64EncodedJwtAndRefreshToken = btoa(encodeURI(`${localStorage.getItem('userToken')}:${localStorage.getItem('refreshToken')}`));
        const url = this.login_api_endpoints + 'RefreshToken/';
        this.asyncResult = await this.post(url, JSON.stringify(base64EncodedJwtAndRefreshToken))
          .toPromise();
        console.log('First Promise resolved.')
        if (this.asyncResult !== null) {
          localStorage.setItem('userToken', this.asyncResult.jwtToken)
          localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', this.asyncResult.refreshToken)

        }

      }
```

both method runs properly but once getTokenfromService() executes the post request, console error pops as ***Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined***

this happens for each and every http requests, above is a example . Small help is really appreciated !

Answer (score 2):

You cannot `subscribe` to a Promise. Change:

```
this.getOriginalDataset(url).then((val)=>{
this.getTokenfromService()
return(val)
```

To:

```
return from(this.getOriginalDataset(url)).pipe(
  tap(() => this.getTokenfromService())
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use await to get the data

```
await this.getTokenfromService()
```

Please let me know if you still have any error

Comment: Thank you for the responses, But i don't want any data to be returned from the  getTokenfromService() method. I'am going to save those data in the local storage

Comment: I dont get what you mean ? My suggest is you using await to make your code work because your getTokenfromService() method is using async

Comment: As you can see asyncResult  is a await and its data is saving in the localStorage  as tokens